# Showing results from a database

Tags: php, mysql

I have one problem with showing records from my database because i work with middle tables. But i'm going to try to explain.
I have next tables in my database :

- **type** (*id, naam*)
- **shops**(*id, naam, type_id*, ... not important)
- **product**(*id, naam*, ... not important)
- **product_shop_tt** (*id, product_id, shop_id*) - that is my middle table
  between product en shops
- **orders**(*id, user_id, status*)
- **order_details**(*id, order_id, user_id, product_shop_tt_id*)
- **user**(*id, naam, not important*)

Now i have next code :

```
<?php

$rezKor = mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT * FROM korisnici WHERE email = '". $_COOKIE["korisnik"] ."' LIMIT 1");
$redKor = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rezKor);
$user_id =  $redKor["id"];

$rezOrders = mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE user_id = ". $user_id ." AND status = 0 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
$redOrders = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rezOrders);
$brRez = mysqli_num_rows($rezOrders);

$rezOrdDetails = mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT * FROM order_details WHERE order_id = ". $redOrders["id"] ."");

while($redOrdDetails = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rezOrdDetails)){
    $rezTT = mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT * FROM product_shop_tt WHERE id = ". $redOrdDetails["product_shop_tt_id"] ."");
    $redTT = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rezTT);
    $brTT = mysqli_num_rows($rezTT);

    $i = 0;
    $rezShop = mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT * FROM shops WHERE id = ". $redTT["shop_id"] ."");
    while($redShop = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rezShop)){
        if($i == 0){
            echo $redShop["naam"] . "<br />";
        }
        $i++;
        $rezProdukt = mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT * FROM producten WHERE id = ". $redTT["product_id"] ."");
        while($redProduct = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rezProdukt)){
            echo "<br />Ime produkta : " . $redProduct["naam"] . "<br />";
        }
    }
}

echo "<div style=\"clear:both;\"></div><div class=\"footer\" style=\"position: fixed;bottom: 0;width: 100%;left:0;\">
    <a href=\"home.php\" title=\"Ga terug\" class=\"col-xs-6 col-sm-6 btn btn-info\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left\"></span> Niets toevoegen</a>
    <button class=\"col-xs-6 col-sm-6 btn btn-danger\" type=\"submit\" name=\"btnNaruci\" id=\"btnNaruci\">
        Leg in winkelmand <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right\"></span><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right\"></span><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right\"></span>
    </button>
</div>";

?>
```

I want to get the next output :

```html
<h1>Type of the shops</h1><br />
<h3>The name of the first shop</h3>
<ul>
  <li>Product from the first shop</li>
  <li>Product from the first shop</li>
</ul><br />
<h3>The name of the second shop</h3>
<ul>
  <li>Product from the second shop</li>
  <li>Product from the second shop</li>
</ul><br /><br />

<h1>Type of the shops</h1><br />
<h3>The name of the next shop</h3>
<ul>
  <li>Product from shop</li>
  <li>Product from shop</li>
</ul><br />
<h3>The name of the new shop</h3>
<ul>
  <li>Product from the new shop</li>
  <li>Product from the new shop</li>
</ul>
```

But with my code i get next :

```html
<div>Type of the shops</div>
<div>The name of the first shop</div>
<div>Product from the first shop</div><br />

<div>Type of the shops</div>
<div>The name of the first shop</div>
<div>Product from the first shop</div><br />

<div>Type of the shops</div>
<div>The name of the first shop</div>
<div>Product from the first shop</div><br />
```

Thus i want to show all products from the same shop bellow the name of that shop. Now i get for every product the name of the shop and the type of the shop.

I hope I was able to explain well.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This code could all be reduced by using a `JOIN` statement. But, if you want to keep your current format, you need to store your shop name, ie. `$redShop["naam"]` to a variable, and only echo it if it is not the current value. for example - `$currentShop = ''; ... if ($redShop["naam"] != $currentShop) { echo $redShop["naam"]; $currentShop = $redShop["naam"];}`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm going to try that.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Sean.

```
<?php

    $rezOrders = mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE user_id = ". $user_id ." AND status = 0 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
    $redOrders = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rezOrders);


    $rez = mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT product_shop_tt.*, shops.*, shops.naam as shopNaam, producten.*, producten.naam as prodNaam, order_details.*, type.*, type.naam as typeNaam 
                                FROM order_details INNER JOIN product_shop_tt ON order_details.product_shop_tt_id = product_shop_tt.id
                                INNER JOIN shops ON shops.id = product_shop_tt.shop_id
                                INNER JOIN producten ON producten.id = product_shop_tt.product_id 
                                INNER JOIN type ON type.id = shops.type_id 
                                WHERE order_id = ". $redOrders["id"] ."");

    $currentType = "";
    $currentShop = "";
    while($red = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rez)){
        if ($red["typeNaam"] != $currentType){
                echo "Type : " . $red["typeNaam"] . "<br />";
                $currentType = $red["typeNaam"];
            }
        if ($red["shopNaam"] != $currentShop){
                echo "Shop : " . $red["shopNaam"] . "<br />";
                $currentShop = $red["shopNaam"];
            }
                echo "Product : " . $red["prodNaam"] . "<br />"; 
        }
?>
```

This is the code that does what I needed.

Many thanks to @Sean! Cheers